# Duplicate Github actions not appearing in PR

Tags: github-actions, pull-request, cicd

I have a mono-repo with tests that run after a deployment. This Github workflow is triggered by `on: [deployment_status]` and since there are 2 deploys, this is triggered 2 times. The issue is that only one of these triggered tests appears in the PR view, while both tests appear in the actions tab for the repo.

```yaml
name: Tests
on: [deployment_status]
jobs:
  job:
    if: github.event.deployment_status.state == 'success'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout 
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Run Cypress 
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v5
```

I tried adding 2 jobs to this workflow but this just led to the workflow being triggered twice with  2 jobs

Answer (score 0):

I got the workflow working within a monorepo with the GitHub Action `patrickedqvist/wait-for-vercel-preview`. Because with this action, I can set an environment. I created a separate workflow for each app.

```
name: Tests for one app
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: ["main"]
  paths:
    - 'package.json'
    - 'apps/myApp/**'
    - .github/workflows/end-to-end-testing-myApp.yml
jobs:
  run-end-to-end-tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    steps:
      - name: Waiting for 200 from the Vercel Preview
        uses: patrickedqvist/wait-for-vercel-preview@v1.3.1
        id: waitFor200
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          max_timeout: 60
          environment: SET THE ENVIRONMENT HERE
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Run Cypress
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v5
        with:
          project: ./apps/myApp
          wait-on: ${{ steps.waitFor200.outputs.url }}
        env:
          CYPRESS_BASE_URL: ${{ steps.waitFor200.outputs.url }}
```

I got the environment name by running the following workflow first. Maybe there is an easier way to do this:

```
name: ci
on: [push, deployment, deployment_status]
jobs:
  show-event:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Dump GitHub context
        env:
          GITHUB_CONTEXT: ${{ toJson(github) }}
        run: echo "$GITHUB_CONTEXT"
```